# Como ordenar boxplots pela média ou mediana no R

Tags: r

Como ordenar uma série de boxplots pela mediana ou média?

O comando utilizado: `boxplot(base$y~base$FID)` ordena os gráficos pela ordem da variável base$FID, eu precisaria que a ordenação fosse feita pela média ou mediana da variável base$y.

Segue  base exemplo:

```
FID  y
1   -0,078
1   3,855
1   2,287
1   2,112
2   -0,245
2   0,462
2   1,282
2   1,128
3   -0,058
3   -0,990
3   -0,144
3   -1,336
4   -0,120
4   -4,286
4   -1,295
4   -1,022
5   1,242
5   2,599
5   2,278
5   3,032
```

Comment: Você poderia fornecer mais informações, sua questão não está clara. Você quer reordenar estes dados ou os gráficos gerados por estes dados? O que é FID, divide em os dados em grupos, ou y, são os dados, é isso?

Comment: Olá Jean, obrigado pelo feedback, adicionei mais informações de forma a evitar ambiguidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa transformar a variável FID em `factor` de forma ordenada. 
Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
dados <- 
  data.frame(
    FID = rep(1:5, each = 5),
    y = 25:1
  )
medianas <- tapply(dados$y, dados$FID, median)
dados$FID <- factor(dados$FID, levels = names(medianas)[order(medianas)])
boxplot(y ~ FID, data = dados)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui ordenei pela mediana, para ordenar pela média, basta trocar o comando `tapply(dados$y, dados$FID, median)` por `tapply(dados$y, dados$FID, mean)`.